# CSS - Why are the boxes in the container when float is NOT used?

Tags: css, css-float

Why is it that when I have three boxes in a div without floating them, the outer div wraps around them, but when I add the float, the outer div collapses?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<style>
#OuterWrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px BLACK dotted;
    text-align: left;
}

.Box {
    float: left; // remove this float and the outer wrapper wraps the three boxes
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: BLUE;
    border: 1px WHITE SOLID;
}
</style>
<div id="OuterWrapper">
    <div class="Box"></div>
    <div class="Box"></div>
    <div class="Box"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because floating elements doesn't affect the size of the parent element. You can use the `overflow` style to make the element contain the children.

Also: You should have a `doctype` tag so that the page isn't rendered in Quirks Mode. Your `style` element should be in the `head` element. The `</html>` tag was missing.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
#OuterWrapper {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px BLACK dotted;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.Box {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: BLUE;
    border: 1px WHITE SOLID;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="OuterWrapper">
    <div class="Box"></div>
    <div class="Box"></div>
    <div class="Box"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, explanation, and advice. You did, however, identity your CSS as JavaScript. You didn't mean to do that, did you?

Comment: @Evik James: You are right. My fingers did that by themselves... :)

Comment: Make sure that if you're using `overflow: hidden` on the container to contain the floats that you also do not set an explicit height on it.

Comment: If you're going to add a doctype, you might as well use the HTML5 one, `<!DOCTYPE html>`, since their only practical purpose is triggering Standards Mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear after the bottom div:

```
<div style='clear: both'></div>
```

Using `clear: both` will force the outer wrapper div to advance below the last floated box. Here's the full snippet:

```
<div id="OuterWrapper">
    <div class="Box"></div>
    <div class="Box"></div>
    <div class="Box"></div>
    <div style='clear: both'></div>
</div>
```

Of course, you could also create a helper class in your CSS file:

```
.ClearBoth {
    clear: both;
}
```

and apply that class to the div after the final box.

Comment: I've had a ton of problems using clear in the past. I will give this a try though.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `overflow:hidden;` style to the wrapper div.

Comment: Yup, that's the normal modern workaround, as I understand it. As to the actual original question, my answer would be, "because that's how it's specified, even if it does confuse the heck out of everyone when they first discover it."

Comment: You had the right answer, but an explanation would have helped me out.  Thanks!!!!